# Can Java interfaces have constructors?

Tags: java, interface

ActionListener is a interface but why can i create instance object?

```
   JButton button = new JButton("Button1");

   ActionListener me = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ae.getActionCommand());  
        }
    };
    button.addActionListener(me);
```

Or what else? I am not sure. Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

What you're seeing here is called an anonymous class: `me` will be assigned an instance of an anonymous (un-named) class that implements the `ActionListener` interface.

Comment: And one more, sir. can I say that events in java implement polymorphism?

Comment: @kimleng: I don't even know what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry sir, I am poor in English. I mean, do Events in Java have  polymorphism's characteristic?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike say C#, Java's interfaces cannot prescribe a constructor.

What you are doing in your code is creating an anonymous class that extends `java.lang.Object` (which does have a default constructor) and implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2):

What you have instantiated is an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).  In short, it's an in-line way to both define a class that has no name and instantiate an instance of that class in one statement.  You'll only ever be able to refer to anonymous inner classes by the super class they implement or extend.  In the case of this question, the super class is the ActionListener interface.

When you compile your code, there will be an extra .class file that exists with a name like this: `OuterClass$1.class`.  That is the class file that represents the anonymous inner class you've defined.

If you want to learn more, check out this section in the JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5

Answer (score 1):

Because you're implementing the interface with your anonymous class

Answer (score 1):

`ActionListener` itself is an interface, indeed.

However, the construct in your code is an anonymous inner class, meaning that your interface was implemented by that inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are creating is an anonymous subclass of `Object.class` that implements the interface. So you are "inheriting" the Constructor from Object, not from the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating an instance of `ActionListener`. You are creating an anonymous class which implements `ActionListener` and you are providing that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

ActionListener is in fact an interface which can not be instantiated.

However, by defining public void actionPerformed() locally you are allowing the interface to act like a class.

This is legal:

```
 ActionListener me = new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(...){...};
 };
```

This is not:

```
ActionListener me = new ActionListener();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You **can't** have `constructor` in `Interface` in java.

**2.** What you saw here is an `Anonymous Class`, which is **declared and initialized simultaneously**, and it must **extend or implement a class or interface respectively**.